# Finding difference of days (comparing against current date)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Dataframe with sales data as below:

```
bill_no,sale_date
1001,2018-12-11
1002,2018-12-15
1003,2018-12-14
1004,2018-12-14
1005,2018-12-17
```

I am trying to filter out bill_no that are 3 days older as compared to current date. Below is what I have tried:

```
today = datetime.date.today().isoformat()
today
```

The above returns 2018-12-17

I am trying to check df['sale_date'] with today as below:

```
df['sale_date'] = (df['sale_date'] - today)
```

The above throws an error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert all data to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Timestamp.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.normalize.html):

```
today = pd.Timestamp.today().normalize()
print (today)
2018-12-17 00:00:00

df['sale_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sale_date'])

df['sale_date'] = (df['sale_date'] - today)
print (df)
   bill_no sale_date
0     1001   -6 days
1     1002   -2 days
2     1003   -3 days
3     1004   -3 days
4     1005    0 days
```